# Conjecture on product of first $n$ primes.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I was recently studying about **reduced residue systems** , and then I stumbled upon an **idea**.

Let $P$ represent the set of all primes.

Let $P_{n}\#$ denote the product of the first $n$ primes and let $P_{n}$ denote the $n^{th}$ prime.

Let $S$ be a set such that, $S=\{ (x_{1},x_{2}) : x_{1},x_{2} \in P \wedge P_{n-1}^{2} < x_{1}\cdot x_{2} < P_{n}\# \}$

My conjecture is:

$P_{n}\# - 1$ is a prime if,

$P_{n}\#  \not \equiv K\cdot A + 1 \pmod{P_{n-1}\#} $ $\forall$  $(K,A) \in S$

For example:
Let's take $n=3$.

$P_2\# =6$

$S=\phi$

Hence,  $P_3\# -1 =29$ is prime.

Let's take $n=4$.

$P_3\# =30$

$S=\{(7,7),(11,7),(7,11),(11,11),(11,13),(13,11),(13,13),(7,17),(17,7),(11,17),(17,11),(7,19),(19,7),(11,19),(19,11)\}$

Hence,  $P_4\# -1 =209$ ($209 = 19 \cdot 11$) is not prime 
since $(7,17)$, $(17,7)$, $(19,11)$, $(11,19)$ satisfy the conditions.

Similarly, $P_{7} \# -1$ is not prime since $P_{7} \# \equiv 41\cdot 11719$ (mod $P_{6} \#$)

If there are any proofs or counter examples for this conjecture, it would be of great help.

Comment: I am in the middle of making an algorithm for generating primes which is more efficient than the sieve of Eratosthenes. But my algorithm can only work in all intervals only if my conjecture is true. So if I can get proofs for my conjecture, I can complete my Prime-generating algorithm. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't $p_n$#$\equiv 0\mod p_{n-1}$# ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74247/discussion-between-peter-and-vishaal-selvaraj).

Comment: You mean you don't have a suitable program to check your conjecture, like Mathematica or MATLAB. But you do have *access* to such a program if you have an Internet connection. You can do some things with Wolfram Alpha and still more with the Wolfram Cloud Lab.

Comment: @RobertSoupe No I don't have a computer right now, its not working. So I am using my mobile, but writing complex scripts in mobile takes time.

Comment: "we can generate larger primes at a relatively faster rate than the sieve algorithm" seems to indicate a misunderstanding.  Sieves are use to generate prime in order, or to efficiently remove all small factors from a range.  Just generating some big primes is a different task and really not very hard unless one makes the size very large (tens of thousands of digits for general form, millions for special forms).

Comment: @DanaJ I mean generating each and every prime in a large interval like 10000000-100000000000 in 8 min.

Comment: Yeah... I can identify. For me to write a tweet on a mobile device would take me longer than it takes President Donald J. Treason. It would take me forever to go to Mathics.net type `SetAttributes[Prime, Listable]` followed by `Select[Table[Times@@Prime[Range[n]], {n, 20}] - 1, PrimeQ]`. And then it would be a pain to put the results into the OEIS to get http://oeis.org/A057705

Comment: But on the other hand, pun intended, you have in the palm of your hand more computing power than Prof. Donald Knuth had in a big room computer when he was your age.

Comment: @RobertSoupe OK, fine I get your point.

Comment: @VishaalSelvaraj Your example range takes about 1 minute using my SoE on single core of a Macbook.  primesieve's SoE takes 30 seconds. That's generating the sieve and walking it for each prime.  Segmented of course. This doesn't invalidate anything, but it points out that you need to compare against good implementations of existing methods.

Comment: @DanaJ I just gave a approximated time period , it doesn't mean that it took exactly 8 min. Try calculating the time required yo generate primes less than 1000000000000000000

Comment: No need, I'll just wait for your paper showing a new sublinear algorithm for sieving primes.  [It is possible.  Helfgott published a modified sieve this year]